# Codeigniter 4 reuse of CSRF token in AJAX modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Scenario:

I am developing CMS system and I wan to add some categories to the objects (pages, posts, media etc.). In my view, to save a new category I use HTML form placed in Bootstrap modal which is sent via AJAX to my controller. The CSRF protection is enabled on the entire site.

While sending the data for the first time, I pass the CSRF token name and hash via form. Once being processed by PHP code in controller, I want to pass CSRF values in the response so I will be able to "re-use" the form in the modal (e.g. display error messages or/and create another category).

Yet, I am not able to access the `get_csrf_token_name()` and `get_csrf_hash()` methods to pass values back to the view.

In my view admmin/category/create.php:

```
...
<!-- CREATE CATEGORY MODAL MODAL -->
    <div class="modal" id="createCategory" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Nová kategorie</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Zavřít"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">  
                    <form action="" method="post" id="createCategoryForm">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?= csrf_hash(); ?>" name="<?= csrf_token(); ?>" id="csrf">

                        <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="title" class="form-label">Název kategorie</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="">
                        </div>   
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createCategoryConfirm">Vytvořit novou kategorii</button>
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

...

<script>
    $('#head').on('click', '.create', function() {

        $('#createCategory').modal('show');
        $('#createCategoryForm').attr('action', '<?= base_url(); ?>/admin/category/create');

        $('#createCategoryConfirm').click(function(e) {            
            e.preventDefault();         
           
            var url = $('#createCategoryForm').attr('action');
            var csrfElement = $('#csrf');
            var csrfName = csrfElement.attr('name');
            var csrfHash = csrfElement.attr('value');
            var categoryTitle = $('input[name=title]').val();

            var data = {
                [csrfName]: csrfHash,
                'title': categoryTitle
            };
            
            console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result); 

                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.log(result); 
                },
            });
        });
    });
        
</script>
```

In my controller Category.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\CategoryModel;
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;


class Category extends BaseController {

    protected $model;
    protected $validator;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct() { 
        $this->model = new CategoryModel();
        $this->validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
        $this->security =  \Config\Services::security();
        helper(['form', 'date', 'url']);
    }

...

    public function create() {
        $response = [];

        // This part of code returns error
        // 
        // $response['csrf'] = array(
        //     'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
        //     'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        // );

        $response['security'] = $this->security;
        
        if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {

            $newCategory = [
                'title' => $this->request->getVar('title'),
                'slug' => url_title($this->request->getVar('title')),
                'author' => session()->get('id'),
                'created_at' => Time::now('Europe/Prague')->toDateTimeString(),
                'updated_at' => Time::now('Europe/Prague')->toDateTimeString(),
                'parent' => '0'
            ];

            $this->validation->run($newCategory, 'categoryRules');

            if (!empty($this->validation->getErrors())) {
                $this->model->save($newCategory);   
                $response['errors'] = $this->validation->getErrors();
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                $this->model->save($newCategory);   
                $response['success'] = 'New category was created';
                echo json_encode($response);

            }
        }          
    }

...
```

In the browser console, the AJAX response is `POST http://localhost/admin/category/create 500 (Internal Server Error)` with full response:

```
code: 500
file: "D:\Web\XAMPP\htdocs\lenka\app\Controllers\Admin\Category.php"
line: 38
message: "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Security\Security::get_csrf_token_name()"
title: "Error"
```

Could anyone please see the issue here? Is there any good solution on how to reuse CSRF tokens in CI4? I tried set config values of CSRF regenerate both to true and false, with no effect.

Comment: in your ajax success, you need to update your hidden input#csrf with new csrf values you created in controller

Comment: well, thats the point - I am not able to generate them in controller: 

`$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()` and `$this->security->get_csrf_hash()` is ending in `Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Security\Security::get_csrf_token_name()`

Comment: that method was used in CI3.x, in CI4.x you do `<input type="hidden" name="<?= csrf_token() ?>" value="<?= csrf_hash() ?>" />` see from the [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Answer (score 1):

update this line cod in .ENV
**or**
app/config/security

CSRF Regenerate = **false**

Answer (score 0):

substitute this:

```
 var data = {
            [csrfName]: csrfHash,
            'title': categoryTitle
        };
        
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result); 

            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(result); 
            },
        });
```

for this:

```
 var data = {
            'title': categoryTitle
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                [csrfName]: csrfHash,
                data
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result); 

            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(result); 
            },
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).